# Is it possible to load the contents of a text file directly into zshrc on start?

Tags: shell, zsh

I have a bunch of shell scripts in my zshrc file that I have to change every now and then and I was thinking it would be nice to move them all to a separate file that would be included in zshrc when I start a terminal session?

Comment: use `source` in your zshrc file?

Comment: can you elaborate what `load the contents` means? either way add your commands in your `~/.zshrc` and optionally source it as @shawn mentioned

Comment: @moghwan as in zsh should be have as though the lines in the text file are lines in .zshrc - I'll try the source thing

Answer (score 0):

You can run any file containing a Zsh script with

```
source <file>
```

or

```
. <file>
```

The difference between `source` and `.` is that, unless `<file>` is an absolute path, `source` will always first look if it can find `<file>` in the current dir, whereas `.` will never do so.